# How to set text of a label according radio type input?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, input

**JS code**

```
          <script>
    handleClick = function(val) {
          document.getElementById('selectnumber').innerHTML = val;
      };
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
 <ul><li><fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" onclick="handleClick('star5')" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star4"  onclick="handleClick('star4')" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star3"  onclick="handleClick('star3')" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star2"  onclick="handleClick('star2')"name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
<input type="radio" id="star1"  onclick="handleClick('star1')" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>
                <asp:Button ID="Rating_btn" runat="server" Text="Rate" OnClick="Rating_btn_Click"/>
<br /><asp:Label ID="selectnumber" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

css code

```
.rating {float:left;}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0); }

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:1.2;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5); }

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {content: '★ ';}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #f70;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow:1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

.rating > label:active {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:2px; }
```

I'm trying to get the value of the star and display it on my screen. Unfortunately it is not doing it.

Comment: Your `openNav` and `closeNav` provide no value to this question. But since you posted it, I would recommend not setting styles with JS but instead adding and removing css classes

Comment: What you set up will only evaluate what is select on initial page load, which, from what you have show currently, will be nothing because no radios are `selected`.  This is why I suggested using `onClick`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Why did you add css?

Comment: the windows.handleclick dont work

Comment: i add it cause i thought it might be one of the cause to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's probably the most straight-forward way to do it.

(Yes there's are other ways, yes there are better ways, but if you aren't familiar with getting/setting values with JS this is about as straight-forward as you can get).

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" onclick="handleClick('star5')" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4"  onclick="handleClick('star4')" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3"  onclick="handleClick('star3')" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2"  onclick="handleClick('star2')"name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1"  onclick="handleClick('star1')" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

<label id="selectnumber" runat="server" Text=""></label>
```

**JS**

```
function handleClick(val) {
  document.getElementById('selectnumber').innerHTML = val;
};
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfthm25/1/

**Example.html**

```
<html>
<fieldset class="rating">
<legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" onclick="handleClick('star5')" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4"  onclick="handleClick('star4')" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3"  onclick="handleClick('star3')" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2"  onclick="handleClick('star2')"name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1"  onclick="handleClick('star1')" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

<label id="selectnumber" runat="server" Text=""></label>
<script>
    function handleClick(val) {
          document.getElementById('selectnumber').innerHTML = val;
      };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: tried did not worked it may be cause i aint calling the function in my html code how can i do it?

Comment: throw a `debugger` or an `alert` in the function and see if it is even getting hit

Comment: how do i do it srry its aint my Strong domain

Comment: and how do i do it?

Comment: full example posted... if you copy that to `Example.html` and open in your browser it will work

Comment: No.. The example given does not use classes

Comment: where is the example?

Comment: It's the part that says `Example.html` there is also a working example if you click the link under `JSFiddle`

Comment: it maybe cause my class i eill add it

Comment: LOL... If it's not working its because you don't know how to copy and paste

Comment: its working when the css is not handled in a new blanked page

Comment: You are probably including something else that is breaking it